# Serial communication won't print out any results

Tags: javascript, serial-port, p5.js, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am pretty new to all of this and really need to get this working in time for my assessments to come around. Unfortunately, I am completely stuck. I've been able to make p5.js read the output of a single button and of a joystick and react accordingly, but I can't get it to print out the value, I would be getting out of my setup.

Setup: 4 buttons, that all get checked for being on or off and a value variable that tells me if and which buttons are on and off by adding specific numbers together. (Can post the Arduino Code if necessary)

Is there any reason my Code in P5.Js isn't working right now? (No output whatsoever from serial communication) (probs to Scott Fitzgerald for the code groundwork)

```
let serial; // variable for the serial object
let value = "waiting for data"; // variable to hold the data


function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  // serial constructor
  serial = new p5.SerialPort();
  // get a list of all connected serial devices
  serial.list();
  // serial port to use - you'll need to change this
  serial.open('COM7');
  // callback for when the sketchs connects to the server
  serial.on('connected', serverConnected);
  // callback to print the list of serial devices
  serial.on('list', gotList);
  // what to do when we get serial data
  serial.on('data', gotData);
  // what to do when there's an error
  serial.on('error', gotError);
  // when to do when the serial port opens
  serial.on('open', gotOpen);
  // what to do when the port closes
  serial.on('close', gotClose);
}

function serverConnected() {
  console.log("Connected to Server");
}

// list the ports
function gotList(thelist) {
  console.log("List of Serial Ports:");

  for (let i = 0; i < thelist.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + " " + thelist[i]);
  }
}

function gotOpen() {
  console.log("Serial Port is Open");
}

function gotClose() {
  console.log("Serial Port is Closed");
  value = "Serial Port is Closed";
}

function gotError(theerror) {
  console.log(theerror);
}

// when data is received in the serial buffer

function gotData() {
  let currentString = serial.readLine(); // store the data in a variable
  trim(currentString); // get rid of whitespace
  if (!currentString) return; // if there's nothing in there, ignore it
  console.log(currentString); // print it out
  value = currentString; // save it to the global variable
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  fill(0, 0, 0);
  text(value, 10, 10); // print the data to the sketch

  // in this example, we are reciving a 0 and a 1
  // if the button is not pressed we get a 0
  //if (latestData == 0) {
   // ellipse(width / 2, height / 2, 100, 100);
  //} else { // if it is pressed, we get a 1
   // rectMode(CENTER);
    //rect(width / 2, height / 2, 100, 100);
  if (value == 0) {
        console.log("NO SENSOR")
    }
    // Test first bit:
    if (value % 2 == 1) {
        console.log("FIRST SENSOR")
    }
  
    // Test second bit:
    if ((value >> 1) % 2 == 1) {
        console.log("SECOND SENSOR")
    }

    if ((value >> 2) % 2 == 1) {
        console.log("THIRD SENSOR")
    }
    if ((value >> 3) % 2 == 1) {
        console.log("FOURTH SENSOR")
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening? Can you print out the inputs from arduino? And your code looks like it tells you when the serial port is opened or closed. Are they working? Is it telling you that the port is open, yet you don't see any inputs?

Comment: So the Arduino code in this example makes sure that there is only 1 number as an input ranging between 0 for nothing and 15 for all buttons. Serial communication is actually happening, but no data seems to be arriving

Comment: `
void setup() {
 pinMode(Button_1, INPUT);
 pinMode(Button_2, INPUT);// put your setup code here, to run once:
 pinMode(Button_3, INPUT);
 pinMode(Button_4, INPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // Building the bit pattern for the sensors:
  int value = 0;

  if (digitalRead(Button_1) == HIGH) {
    value = value + 1;
  }

  if (digitalRead(Button_2) == HIGH) {
    value = value + 2;
  }
  
  if (digitalRead(Button_3) == HIGH) {
    value = value + 4;
  }
  
  if (digitalRead(Button_4) == HIGH) {
    value = value + 8;
  }
  Serial.println(value);
}
`